# I want to capture an event from object tag

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I have a principal Page:

```
<script src='js/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(readyFn);

    function readyFn() {
        $('#cartelera01').attr('data','prueba5.html');

        function doSomething(){
            console.log('do something when the event of the object is triggered');
        }
    }
</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object id="cartelera01" type="text/html" data="" width="500" height="300" style='overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: hidden;'
                    onpagehide="doSomething()" 
            ></object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and have a prueba5.html too:

```
script src='js/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(readyFn);

    function readyFn() {
        console.log('page init');
        setTimeout(function() 
            {
                console.log('after 3 seconds, page end'); //here I want to fire event object of principal page
            }, 3000);
    }
</script>

<html> 
<body>
    <div style="left:0;width:300;heigth:200;background:black;">
        <img src="bola1.png" style='top:0;left:0px;width:180;height:180px;position:absolute;'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want that when the page prueba5.html finishes automatically (after 3 seconds), the object "cartelera01" of principal page to know that the page prueba5.html was over, and do something.
Can anybody help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ajax or run prueba5.html as an invisible iframe within your principal page, make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to think of Ajax to do what you want?
With Ajax you can make a call for a page to load another page without changing the header of the main page, and then at the end you can generate the response to the notification ...

see the example [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp)

Comment: The page prueba5.html have javascript code. It is not only html page... I probed it but doesn't work. If it is only html works fine, but I need javascript code....